# Why in JavaScript does {} + {} become "[object Object][object Object]" but [] + [] becomes an empty string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, constructor

Why in JavaScript does **`{} + {}`** become `"[object Object][object Object]"` but **`[] + []`** becomes an empty string `""`? Are they not both objects in JavaScript? So why is the result of concatenation different? Any particular reason?

Why is the result not `"[object Array][object Array]"` for example?

Comment: `Array.prototype.toString` overrides the default behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `+` is used with objects, the objects are coerced to strings and the results are concatenated.

When a plain object is turned into a string, you get `[object Object]`:

```js
console.log(
  String({})
);
```

On the other hand, when an array is turned into a string, internally, `.join(',')` is called on the array, joining all elements by a comma. But if no elements exist in the array, the joined result is the empty string.

Just for the sake of curiosity (don't do this in real code!), if you deleted `Array.prototype.join`, `String(someArr)` would no longer be able to call `.join`, and the result would be `[object Array]`, because the constructor of the object being turned into a string is named `Array`:

```js
delete Array.prototype.join;
console.log(String([])); // Result: [object Array]
```

```html
Look at the results in your browser console, not the snippet console
(because removing Array.prototype.join breaks the snippet console)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems javascript call **join** function each time concatenation happens on Array which causes this not printing `"[object Array][object Array]"` like how it does on Object like `"[object Object][object Object]"`, so that weirdo result happens.